# How to create a non-standard string literal with parameters in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am creating a **non-standard string literal** with a macro with something like that:

```
macro R13_str(p)
    rotate(13, p)
end
```

and it works. I can call it as:

```
R13"abc"
```

But I would like to declare the macro to work with any integer, like:

```
R1"abc"
```

or

```
R244"abc"
```

Let's say the function `rotate()` is:

```
function rotate(shift_amount::Int64, s::String)

    # Ensure the shift is no bigger than the string
    shift = shift_amount ≤ length(s) ? shift_amount : shift_amount % length(s)

    # Circular shift
    return s[end-shift+1:end] * s[1:end-shift]
end
```

How can I do that? I have checked all the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#meta-non-standard-string-literals), but it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't see how to achieve exactly what is required. But the following might be good enough:

```
julia> macro R_str(p,flag)
           rotate(flag, p)
       end
@R_str (macro with 1 method)

julia> R"hello"3
"llohe"

julia> R"abc"1
"cab"

julia> R"abc"244
"cab"
```

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#meta-non-standard-string-literals

Trying to conform to OP call format:

```
julia> macro rework(expr)
       if expr.head != :macrocall return expr ; end
       r = String(expr.args[1])
       rr = parse(Int, r[3:findfirst('_',r)-1])
       :(rotate($rr, $(expr.args[3])))
       end
@rework (macro with 1 method)

julia> @rework R13"hello"
"llohe"
```

This macro could help to read the prepared test cases??

Comment: Nice! Thank you, I believe that a flag could be a good solution. But I have a suite of tests like: R13"string" and R15"string" and I would need to declare 26 macros to e able to pass all the tests. That's why I was trying to achieve that.

Comment: @FlavioBarros Added another macro, which would perhaps get closer to support use case.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

```
for n in 0:244
    @eval macro $(Symbol(:R, n, :_str))(s)
        rotate($n, s)
    end 
end
```

While I believe that using flags is the better approach, with this `for` loop I can generate all the macros that I need.

```
Julia> R1"abc" 
Julia> R24"acb" 
Julia> R56"abc"
```

simply work.